# Replacement for inAppBrowser in PWA

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

Is there any good way to get something like an inappbrowser in a pwa?
I need anything that may display a webpage and has customizable navigation buttons. Surely I thought about using iframes but there should be a better way, right?

Reason:
I made a little cross-platform app for a customer, based on angular and cordova, some time ago. Since few months, my customers' workers experience problems getting push notifications and using the in-app chat function, while using devices from samsung and huawei.

Now, because the debugging on these devices are a bit tricky, I tried porting the app to a PWA. This way the issue is not reproducable anymore but... The app needs to load some secured pages in the inappbrowser. This because the called pages need to exchange data (like special hashes) with the app and if this pages are called inside the standard browser (outside of the app), the exchange will fail.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open web pages *within* your PWA, then you should configure the `scope` property in your manifest file:

> The scope defines the set of URLs that the browser considers to be within your app, and is used to decide when the user has left the app. The scope controls the URL structure that encompasses all the entry and exit points in your web app.

I wrote one article [about web manifest configuration](https://dev.to/paco_ita/install-a-pwa-on-the-user-s-device-step-2-27pa) as part of a PWA series. Have a look at it if you want to get more details.